# How to select array elements matching a value from an inner array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("599ec823f896921dbb2855ed"),
    "key1" : "$value",
    "key2" : [
        {
            "Key3" : "$value1"
            "Key4" : "$value2",
            "Key5" : "['v3.1','v3.2','v3.3']",
            "Key6" : "value4",
            "Key7" : "value5",
            "Key8":[
                {"Key9":"value6"},
                {"Key10":"value7"},
                {"Key11":"value8"},
                {"Key12":"value9"},
                {"Key13":"value10"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "Key14" : "$value11"
            "Key15" : "$value12",
            "Key16" : "['v3.11','v3.12','v3.13']",
            "Key17" : "value14",
            "Key18" : "value15",
            "Key19":[
                {"Key20":"value16"},
                {"Key21":"value17"},
                {"Key22":"value18"},
                {"Key23":"value19"},
                {"Key24":"value20"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Following query is returning me empty array, what am I doing wrong?

```
db.hotelCol.aggregate([
  {$project:{
    key2:{
      $filter:{
        input:"$key2",
        as:"lock",
        cond:{ $eq:["$$lock.key5","v3.2"]}
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

I want to get as a result:

```
{
    "Key3" : $value1"
    "Key4" : "$value2",
    "Key5" : "['v3.1','v3.2','v3.3']",
    "Key6" : "value4",
    "Key7" : "value5",
    "Key8":[
        {"Key9":"value6"},
        {"Key10":"value7"},
        {"Key11":"value8"},
        {"Key12":"value9"},
        {"Key13":"value10"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to S.O. I guess you should explain better what you're trying to achieve. The lack of details can make harder to understand your question. If you need some guidance, please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

The `"key5"` property is an "array" so [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) as a condition does not match with a single value. The aggregation logical operators are not as liberal as the general query conditions and don't attempt to match each array element.

There are different operators for this depending on your available version.

For MongoDB 3.4 use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/):

```
db.hotelCol.aggregate([
  { $project:{
    Key2:{
      $filter:{ 
        input:"$Key2",
        as:"lock",
        cond:{ $in:[ "v3.2", "$$lock.Key5" ] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

For versions from MongoDB 2.6, use [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/)

```
db.hotelCol.aggregate([
  { $project:{
    Key2:{
      $filter:{ 
        input:"$Key2",
        as:"lock",
        cond:{ $setIsSubset: [ ["v3.2"], "$$lock.Key5" ] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Note the slightly different notation and intended purpose. But the point is that both are meant to compare "arrays" as opposed to "singular values".

The [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) compares a singular value to an array directly. The [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) operator compares "two arrays" to return is one is a sub-set of the other, meaning they share common elements as a "unique set". In the latter case you wrap the single element with an array to enable the comparison.

Both return a boolean condition in there evaluation, which is what is expected of `"cond"` in the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operation.

> Also note the "case" of the keys used in the statements. It is important that these match the actual structure, otherwise again you will not get a result since key names a "case sensitive".